# How do i connect my database with Angular app

Tags: javascript, php, angular

i am trying to connect my backend database mysql to my app, but not able to do it and get because i don,t know about php. i want my username and password to be checked from the database when they hit log in, i have tried it myself but can't get , please post a solution with little explanation

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { Router } from '@angular/router';
 import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';


 @Component({
   selector: 'login-form',
   templateUrl: './login-form.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./login-form.component.css']
 })
 export class LoginFormComponent implements OnInit {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    form: FormGroup;
   constructor(private router: Router, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
   }

   ngOnInit() {
     this.initf();

   }
   initf() {
     this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
       username: this.username,
       password: this.password
     });
   }
   log() {
 console.log(this.username, this.password);
 if ( this.username === 'admin' && this.password === 'admin') {

       this.router.navigate(['todoapp']);
     }


   }
   }
```

```css
<?php 


 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
 header('Content-Type: application/json');

 if(!isset($_POST)) die();

 session_start();

 $response = [];

 $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test_site');

 $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
 $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);

 $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";

 $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

 echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: after executing the query, you fetch the results and put them in some container, namely arrays, then finally you json encode. you forgot that step

Comment: What error's are you getting? is the problem in php or javascript? Also, your security is poor. First, don't EVER store plaintext passwords in the database. Look into password hashing in php: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php . Secondly, use prepared statements in php: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @Ghost can you edit my code and do i need to change my log() function ts file as it is hard coded there?

Comment: @Artog i will update the security later thanks for that, the problem is i want to log in through my database not hard coded from ts file front end

Answer (score 0):

My friend it is a little longer to explain but i could tell, you could follow this tutorial on how to connect PHP and angular

at this point you have your backend which is in PHP 
https://www.techiediaries.com/php-angular/

but you need to follow this second step on how to build, structure connect you Angular components and services with PHP
https://www.techiediaries.com/php-angular-crud-api-httpclient-forms/

hope this helps